# CSS, HTML, JavaScript достаточно для разработки веб-приложений?

Tags: веб-программирование

Изучаю CSS, HTML, JavaScript. Знаю, что в JavaScript есть функции для обмена данными с сервером. При этом данные пересылаются в формате JSON, реже XML.
Знаю, что картинки можно создавать прямо в браузере, при помощи Canvas.
Файлы с HTML, CSS, JavaScript можно разместить на хостинге, например, на github.
И если веб-приложение создается, например, для соцсети vk или facebook, то надо знать как работать с серверными API.

Итак, для того чтобы начать заниматься разработкой веб-приложений надо знать:

- CSS
- HTML
- JavaScript
- JSON, возможно XML
- серверные API

Подскажите, **какой пункт необходимо добавить в  список?**

Обратите внимание на то, что я не собираюсь заниматься разработкой для серверов.
Пожалуйста, не пишите про то, что без сервера невозможно разработать веб-приложение. Просто вспомните о веб-приложениях для соцсетей, и поймите, что с серверами соцсетей можно работать только через API.

Comment: Если вы точно знаете, что серверные технологии вам не нужны, и перечислили все клиентские технологии, которые вам нравятся - то в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Я не точно знаю, поэтому спрашиваю. Наверное вы со смартфона читаете, и у вас не виден вопрос: **какой пункт необходимо добавить в  список?**

Comment: Если я запрощу ответ "никакой, перечисленного достаточно" - вы отметите его как верный?

Comment: я к тому, что не совсем понятно - вы хотите услышать *мнения* о том, что, возможно (а возможно и нет!) стоило бы добавить (и тогда это оффтопик). Или вы действительно считаете что что-то пропустили, и ждете ответа - что именно?

Comment: Отлично. А вы самый главный специалист по веб-приложениям? Предлагаю подождать ответы других специалистов.

Comment: Хотелось бы получить технически грамотный ответ.

Comment: Да, я самый главный специалист по веб-приложениям. Перечитайте, пожалуйста, раздел справки [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Технически грамотный ответ я вам привел выше - да, всего перечисленного достаточно. Если вам нужно обоснование такого ответа - укажите в вопросе, какого именно обоснования вы ждете.

Comment: Замечательно. Раз так, то как и предлагали, напишите в ответе "перечисленного достаточно". И я его приму.

Comment: И как главный, скажите, пожалуйста, почему удалили вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491527/

Comment: Раз Вы собираетесь заниматься только фронтом (front-end), возможно после изучения нативного JS вам будет интересно (для ускорения разработки и тд. и тп. )) изучить различные фреймворки, библиотеки и тд. которые смогли бы помочь Вам в Вашей работе - ExtJS, JQuery, AngularJS (также Bootstrup, less и тд.), сборщики grunt, gulp. Фронт очень обширен, развивайтесь в любом выбранном направлении

Comment: Вы не уточняете, разработкой приложений **для чего** вы собираетесь заниматься. Вопрос в заголовке вы сформулировали так, что он выглядит общим, а случай-то у вас частный, Вы же собираетесь разрабатывать приложение для уже существующего сервера, у которого есть API, верно?

Comment: @Nunu без понятия, почему удалили вопрос. Его удалил другой модератор. Если хотите - можете задать вопрос об этом [на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @ghostrider, спасибо, фрейморки и средства разработки будут на втором шаге. А на первом собираюсь сосредоточиться на изучении основ.

Comment: @VenZell, ну да, для существующих серверов. Я не собираюсь заниматься разработкой для серверов.

Comment: вообще я бы уже разделял сам JavaScript и современный фронтенд на JavaScript, кроме шуток, изучать там не переизучать сейчас, если речь прямо о веб-приложениях серьезных

Comment: @Nunu, тогда если Вы на данном этапе собираетесь сосредоточится на изучении основ, всего что Вы перечислили будет более чем достаточно. Изучайте не только по докам и книгам, а на живых примерах, придумывайте задачи, свои проекты (тогда будут всплывать различные вопросы - а как то сделать, а это), это все даст Вам хороший опыт, знания, практику написания кода. А дальше уже все станет на свои места, в ходе изучения, написания кода Вы уже поймете чего Вам не хватает, что надо бы еще изучить, какие инструменты, библиотеки, технологии и тд.

Comment: Ваш вопрос провоцирует обмен субъективными мнениями и холивар по поводу личных предпочтений. Пожалуйста, не задавайте такие вопросы. Они не соответствуют формату этого сайта. Прошлый вопрос удалил я — по тем же самым причинам, плюс в нём на самом деле несколько вопросов, часть из которых следовало задавать на Мете.

Comment: Кстати, я отправил вам личное сообщение на другую учётную запись. Чтобы больше не плодить учётки, рекомендую зарегистрироваться на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Перечисленного достаточно, если подразумевать что HTML в списке включает в себя вещи вроде Local Storage, а JS - включает в себя фреймворки.

В зависимости от серверной платформы, может оказатся лишним или JSON, или XML. Или лишними могут быть оба + серверный API, если разрабатываемый сайт должен быть полностью статическим.